# Rspec: How can I test an array push?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am writing some test in Rspec and am trying to push a `carrier` to a `user` via a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.  Below is the test I have written, however the line I have indicated with an arrow does not seem to pass.  I realized I have mocked the carrier but not the user and I'm wondering if this is causing an issue with the HABTM association.  Is this the issue or is there something else I'm missing?  I am new to mocking and stubbing, but trying my best!

```
describe UsersController do
  describe 'get #add_carrier' do
    let(:user) { build(:approved_user) }

    let(:carrier) { mock_model(Carrier).as_null_object }
    before{ Carrier.stub(:find).and_return(carrier) }

    it 'associates the Carrier to the User' do
      expect(user.carriers).to eq []
      user.should_receive(:carriers).and_return([])
  --> (user.carriers).should_receive(:push).with(carrier).and_return([carrier])
      (user.carriers).push(carrier)
      (user.carriers).should include carrier
    end 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stubs are generally used when you want to do a proper unit test and stub out anything but the method under test. Mocks (stubs with expectations) are usually used when you are testing a method that calls a command method (ie a method that has some impact, e.g. altering some data or saving a record) and you want to ensure it is called.

This particular test, given its in a controller, seems to be testing things at the wrong level - it's testing stuff inside the method, not the method itself. Take a look at the [rspec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs).

Not knowing the code you're testing, it's a bit tricky to identify exactly how to test. #add_carrier sounds like a method that should simply test whether a carrier is added, so presumably we could test the message expectation. This test also appears to be testing the getter method #carriers, which seems to be a bit much for one unit test (but I completely understand the desire to have it there).

Also note that sharing the error you're getting would definitely be helpful.

Anyway, try something like the following:

```
describe UsersController do
  describe 'get #add_carrier' do # Should this really be a GET?
    subject { get :add_carrier }

    let(:user) { build(:approved_user) }
    let(:carrier) { mock_model(Carrier).as_null_object }

    before do
      controller.stub(:user) { user }
      Carrier.stub(:find) { carrier }
    end

    it "associates the Carrier to the User" do
      user.carriers.should_receive(:push).with(carrier).and_call_original
      subject
      user.carriers.should include carrier
    end
  end
end
```

No expectations on the original value of user.carriers (that should be tested in User model). No expectations on the details of how push works - again, should be tested elsewhere. Rather, just confirming that the important command message is called. I'm not 100% sure we should even be doing #and_call_original and confirming the results, as those are things we can also test in model unit tests (results of Carrier#push), but for peace of mind I included here.

Note this was all written from memory, so please let me know if any of it doesn't work.